# How to ignore points with same value in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart using Chart.js that works fine except i want the chart to draw a straight line when the y values are the same. For example in the below image i have some data where there are hundreds of consecutive y values of 1. What i want is instead of the chart rendering a point for each consecutive y value of 1 i want a straight line. I have read the documentation for all the options and i didn't see one that fits my needs. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Code:

```
this.$EventsCountChart = new Chart(this.$EventsCountChart, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: timestamps,
                            datasets: [{
                                data: eventCounts,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            legend: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            scales: {
                                xAxes: [{
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: false
                                    }
                                }],
                                yAxes: [{
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        labelString: 'Event Count'
                                    },
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you look at image there are hundreds of values of 1 in a row. What i want is only to show points when y value changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, use the following function to factor your data :

```
function factorData(data) {
   let _data = data.map((e, i, a) => {
      let prev = a[i - 1];
      let next = a[i + 1];
      if (e === prev && e === next) return '' + e;
      return e;
   }).map(e => typeof e === 'string' ? null : e);
   return _data;
}
```

then, set the **`spanGaps`** property to `true` for your dataset, like so :

```
...
datasets: [{
         data: factorData(eventCounts),
         spanGaps: true
         ...
```

see a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jpLy9h46/).

Answer (score 1):

Improving on ɢʀᴜɴᴛ's answer

> To increase performance by 2x:

```
function factorData(data) {
   return data.map((e, i, a) => {
      let prev = a[i - 1];
      let next = a[i + 1];
      if (e === prev && e === next) return null;
      return e;
   });
}
```

(not iterating over the array a second time)

> Also don't forget!

```
...
datasets: [{
  data: factorData(eventCounts),
  spanGaps: true
...
```